# read input containing spaces

Tags: bash, shell

I have my bash shell script working but I need to take into account the use case where when I read  user input it will contain valid white spaces between the words.  It can be multiple word so I need to either need a way to read the entire  line and parse them or change it that the enter a search string as a unique entry and save it for input to my grep search

1. Example 1 time out
2. Example 2 fails to start
3. Example 3 device failed to respond

Thanks!

Comment: If you use `read myvariable`, then it will read a whole line with spaces. If that's what you're doing in your script, you probably have a quoting bug that causes accidental truncation.

Comment: you could grep/count the number of blank characters (`\s`) ?

Comment: A [mcve] that shows the actual attempt and problem encountered would make this a much better question. Until we can see what you tried, we can have no idea of *why* your existing code doesn't work.

Comment: @LoneWanderer, `\s` is not part of POSIX regex syntax, so it's not guaranteed to be available in grep (which is only firmly guaranteed to support POSIX BRE and ERE). Anyhow, even if counting whitespace characters is called for, there's no good reason to use external tools -- bash itself can count characters. `line='one two three four'; line_spaces=${line//[![:space:]]}; echo "Line has ${#line_spaces} spaces"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wasn't aware of that. Good to know. BTW, it is weird that it does not appear on this page https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html while the site is rather complete about regex

Comment: @LoneWanderer, ...the authoritative reference re: what a grep implementation needs to support to call itself POSIX-compliant is http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html, which refers to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html; BRE and ERE don't support *any* backslash-sequence shorthand for character classes at all (except where implementations go beyond the spec).